# Seaborn kdeplot not plotting some data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to get the [Seaborn kdeplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) example to work on my dataset. For some reason, one of my datasets isn't plotting at all, but the other seems to be plotting fine. To get a minimal working example, I have sampled only 10 rows from my very large data sets.

My input data looks like this:

```
#Dataframe dfA
    index   x       y     category
0   595700  5   1.000000    14.0
1   293559  4   1.000000    14.0
2   562295  3   0.000000    14.0
3   219426  4   1.000000    14.0
4   592731  2   1.000000    14.0
5   178573  3   1.000000    14.0
6   553156  4   0.500000    14.0
7   385031  1   1.000000    14.0
8   391681  3   0.999998    14.0
9   492771  2   1.000000    14.0

# Dataframe dfB
    index   x      y      category
0   56345   3   1.000000    6.0
1   383741  4   1.000000    6.0
2   103044  2   1.000000    6.0
3   297357  5   1.000000    6.0
4   257508  3   1.000000    6.0
5   223600  2   0.999938    6.0
6   44530   2   1.000000    6.0
7   82925   3   1.000000    6.0
8   169592  3   0.500000    6.0
9   229482  4   0.285714    6.0
```

My code snippet looks like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="darkgrid")

# Set up the figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

# Draw the two density plots
ax = sns.kdeplot(dfA.x, dfA.y,
             cmap="Reds", shade=True, shade_lowest=False)
ax = sns.kdeplot(dfB.x, dfB.y,
             cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=False)
```

Why isn't the data from dataframe `dfA` actually plotting?

Comment: Are you only creating one axes-object and plot both into the same (or even plotting figure-oriented without some axes)? What about ```f, axarr = plt.subplots(2)``` + ```sns.kdeplot(dfA.x, dfA.y,
             cmap="Reds", shade=True, shade_lowest=False, ax=axarr[0])``` + ```sns.kdeplot(dfB.x, dfB.y,
             cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=False, ax=axarr[1])```

Comment: I'm trying to plot both on the same axis. But dfA doesn't plot even if I comment out the second plot comments

Answer (score 2):

I don't think gaussian KDE is a good fit for either of your datasets. You have one variable with discrete values and one variable where the large majority of values seem to be a constant. This is not well modeled by a bivariate gaussian distribution.

As for what exactly is happening, without the full dataset I cannot say for sure, but I expect that the KDE bandwidth (particularly on the y axis) is ending up very very narrow such that regions with non-negligible density are tiny. You could try setting a wider bandwidth, but my advice would be to use a different kind of plot for this data.